# Does my code prevent people from finding the userID?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm developing a page in PHP which displays a list of patients.

I want the $_POST['userID'] to select the corresponding patient (by triggering a click), the problem is that now I don't want the userID to be displayed to the user (it was in a data variable). I was using this code before:

**PHP**

```
<?php while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) { ?>
    <td data-id="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" class="patient">
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    userID = '<?php echo $_POST['userID ']; ?>';

    $('.patient').each(function(index, elem) {
        if ($(elem).data('id') == userID) {
            $(elem).trigger('click');
        }
    })
</script>
```

I changed it into this, now the data passes a index instead of the user id that will be later used to find the user:

**PHP**

```
    <?php 
        $i=0;
        while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) 
        { 
           $patientArray[$i] = $row[1]; 
    ?>
        <td data-pos="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="patient">
        </td>

    <?php 
            $i++;
        } 
    ?>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
userID = '<?php echo $_POST['userID']; ?>';

<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($patientArray);$i++) { ?>

     pacient = '<?php echo $patientArray[$i]; ?>';

     if (pacient == userID)
     {
            patientpos = '<?php echo $i; ?>';
     }

<?php } ?>

    $('.patient').each(function(index, elem) 
    {   
        if ($(elem).data('pos') == patientpos)
            {
                $(elem).trigger('click');
            }
    })
</script>
```

So, will the second solution prevent people from finding the userID? Is there something unsafe on my code? Or an easier solution?

Comment: Did you 'View Source' in your browser and ctrl-F for the userID?

Comment: `userID = '<?php echo $_POST['userID']; ?>';` No, the user id is not hidden. Why should it be hidden? What danger does exposing it involve

Comment: There is no security issues for user to see it's ID. Better improve security on login, unique urls for user view and so on.

Comment: You are explicitly displaying the `userID` in your client-side code (`userID = '<?php echo $_POST['userID']; ?>';`) so no, this will not prevent people from finding it.

Comment: I don't know what danger it involve, Im working in a company and after they reviewed my code they asked me to hide the users ID. So people can read javascript variables thats it?

Comment: Also, this code is a security nightmare - don't echo back out user input without filtering!

Comment: Normally its not a problem to get your UserID. What is the problem if i know that the UserID for a specific customer is 10424? I could do nothing if there are no security problems with your code. But if you dont want to make it not so "easy" to read, use UUID (36 char String) instead of an Integer as UserID.

Comment: I did filter the code, it is just not show, sorry. $_POST['userID'] = xss_protect($_POST['userID'])

Comment: @Condward If someone is telling you that it being visible is a danger, they should be able to both justify their reasoning and explain an alternative (if they can do neither they should not be doing the review). Ask them for assistance; a code review process should be an opportunity to learn and not just criticise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into using UUIDs and find a php class for creating UUIDs for you.

From Wikipedia:

The intent of UUIDs is to enable distributed systems to uniquely identify information without significant central coordination. In this context the word unique should be taken to mean "practically unique" rather than "guaranteed unique". Since the identifiers have a finite size, it is possible for two differing items to share the same identifier. The identifier size and generation process need to be selected so as to make this sufficiently improbable in practice. Anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with reasonable confidence that the same identifier will never be unintentionally created by anyone to identify something else. Information labeled with UUIDs can therefore be later combined into a single database without needing to resolve identifier (ID) conflicts.

and here is a good read about using guide instead.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/

Answer (score 1):

Your code opens a can of worms. How can you guarantee that your result set will **always** be same in same order?

You open patient list page

```
Order   ID   Name
1       154  Abraham Lincoln
2       97   Abraham Setrakian
```

Then some use enters another patient "Abraham Maslow", then you are in deep trouble.

```
Order   ID   Name
1       154  Abraham Lincoln
2       998  Abraham Maslow
3       97   Abraham Setrakian
```

since 2nd in the list is not Setrakian. Kaboom.

Use some light two-way encryption tool like "RayCrypt". Salt `UserID` with page specific key, then use that. When javascript calls your server side code, you know how to decrypt code. Since that code is salted with page specific key, it is not usable for any other purpose like viewing "http://my.awesome.app/patient/view/97"

Comment: well that data-pos variable is the order of the elements on the array when it was created, it won't change, if for example Lincoln and Setrakian change positions the value in data-pos will still be same. Or am I thinking it wrong? Im going to try the encryption thing. Thanks